# In Passport.js & JWT strategy, what happens to the token after authentication? where is it stored (or where should I store it) and how to read it?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, nestjs

I'm new at authentication.

I'm developing an app with nodeJS using nestJS backend and authentication mechanism of Passport & JWT strategy.

This is a login controller I found in some repo at github.
I've implemented it and it works. I can make an ajax call, authenticate and get a token as a response.

auth.controller.ts:

```
import { Controller, Post, HttpStatus, HttpCode, Get, Response, Body, Param, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { User } from 'user/user.entity';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService,
              private readonly userService: UserService) {}
  @Post('login')
  async loginUser(@Response() res: any, @Body() body: User) {

    if (!(body && body.email && body.password)) {
      return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).json({ message: 'Email and password are required!' });
    }

    const user = await this.userService.findOneByEmail(body.email);

    if (user) {
      if (await this.userService.compareHash(body.password, user.password)) {

        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(await this.authService.createToken(user.email));
      }
    }

    return res.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).json({ message: 'Email or password wrong!' });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to understand why should I return the token to the client?
where should I save the token and how will I be able to read it?
I understand that Passport.js is a middleware that supposed to deal with all of that, but I don't understand how.

In the beginning I thought I'm supposed to save it as an httpOnly cookie but now I'm now sure if necessary or maybe passport is doing something like that "for me".

Here some more code:

auth.module.ts

```
import { Module, MiddlewareConsumer, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { UserModule } from '../user/user.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthController } from '../auth/auth.controller';
import { PatientModule } from '../patient/patient.module'

@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secretKey',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    }),
    UserModule,
    PatientModule
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { JwtPayload } from './jwt-payload.interface';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService,  private readonly userService: UserService,) {}
  async createToken(email) {
    const expiresIn = 3600

    const user: JwtPayload = { email:email};
    const token = await this.jwtService.sign(user);
    return {
      token,
      expiresIn: expiresIn
    };
  }

  async validateUser(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<any> {
    return await this.userService.findOneByEmail(payload.email);
  }
}
```

jwt.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { JwtPayload } from './jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<boolean>  {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Maybe this question will be considered as a bad one but I'm a real newbie in this, I've tried reading the [Passport.js documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/) and [nest relevant docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication) but got to nothing.

Comment: You're using jsonwebtokens so you don't have to do anything on the backend.  Basically you generate the token when the user signs in and pass that token to the frontend.  You don't have to store it in a database or anything because the token is structured in such a way that you can decode it if you have the secret.  Just make sure to pass it to the backend for all requests by adding the header `Authorization: Bearer {your_token}`.

Comment: @DylanAspden What I'm asking is, I've logged in, created a token, sent it as a response to the client and did nothing with it.
now I want to make a request to the server that is protected by an authGuard or whatever, I have to be authenticated for that request, meening the server needs to check who am I, by the token. Where will the server get that token from?
As you said, I need to pass it in the header of the request but for doing that I have to save it somewhere after receiving it when logged in, if I got it right.

Comment: Your server is already handling grabbing the token in your `JwtStrategy` class.  It takes care of everything and then loads your user instance into `request.user`.  If you want to access `request.user` you can create a decorator for that https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators.  You can store the token on the frontend in local storage, that is usually sufficient.  You could alternatively store the token in a cookie.

Comment: @DylanAspden ok, so if the `JwtStrategy` class is handling everything,  why **should** I store that token in the frontend if I do'nt need to send it?

Comment: You have two options to store on frontend, either in local storage (easy) or a cookie with `httpOnly` set to `true` (a bit more work).  Your code right now will work out-of-the-box if you store your token in local storage.  Some people rightly argue that local storage isn't very secure so we would tend to lean towards the cookie solution.  But you know your project best to make that decision.

Comment: @Dylan Aspden So if I got it right, I **have** to store it somewhere in the front for future requests, as long as it did not expire. If I'll choose local storage than passport will "pull" it from there and if I'll choose cookie I'll need write logic for that(?)